# Several Server Errors (No database connect, can't create TCP/IP socket etc

Tags: ip, database, tcp, 500-error, mod-fcgid

My server stops taking requests on my website today. It works for some time, but then the server just stops working and throws several errors:

`500 Internal Server Error`

`Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't create TCP/IP socket (105) in [...] on line 7 Couldn't connect to database. Please try again.`

`mysql_connect(): Host [...] is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'`

`mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper` (this is from Error Log)

Any ideas what might cause it?
operating system is Ubuntu

Comment: What do the mysql logs say is causing the connection errors?

Comment: I don't have access to the mysql log (thanks to my hosting company)

Comment: I'd contact them and ask for it then.  Anything else and you're trying to fix a symptom, not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Someone or something is failing to connect to the mysql server from your host. When the number of errors reaches the max_connect_errors parameter configured on mysql, it stops accepting connections from your host.

Too many possible scenarios... we go from wrong credentials somewhere in your code to some sort of hacking attempt.

I suggest to analize your access_log and dump the traffic to the database in order to identify the source of the failing connections.